# How can I register a MIB module in a different (SNMPv3) context. In SNMP agent side

Tags: python, snmp, agent, pysnmp, mib

I am new to SNMP and I am trying to create SNMP agent in the cloud which will use the context name to distinguish the devices. I am using pysnmp in the agent side. I am also following the sample program available in the 
http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/contents.html

Now I want to know how to add register multiple context name in the agent side and register MIB under this context name. All using the same non-default MIB.

I tried whatever sample codes available in www.snmpalabs.com, But when i use the context name I get Time Out or ENd Of MIB.

```py
def __init__(self, mibObjects):

 snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

 config.addTransport(
      self._snmpEngine, udp.domainName,                              
      udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('127.0.0.1', 161)))

 config.addV3User(self._snmpEngine, 'User', config.usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol, 'PassCode')

 config.addVacmUser(self._snmpEngine, 3, 'User', 'authNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 44555), (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 44555))

 snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

        responder(snmpEngine,snmpContext)

 mibBuilder = snmpContext.getMibInstrum().getMibBuilder()

 loadmib(mibBuilder)

 snmpContext.registerContextName(
                 v2c.OctetString('MyContextName'),
                 instrum.MibInstrumController(mibBuilder)
        )

 MibScalarInstance, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-SMI', 'MibScalarInstance')

 # export our custom mib
 for mibObject in mibObjects:
       nextVar, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(mibObject.mibName,                                
       mibObject.objectType)
       instance = createVariable(MibScalarInstance,          
                                mibObject.valueFunc,                                     
                                mibObject.objectType,                                    
                                nextVar.name, (0,),                                  
                                nextVar.syntax)
      instanceDict = {str(nextVar.name) + "Instance":instance}
      mibBuilder.exportSymbols(mibObject.mibName,
                                        **instanceDict)
```

I just pasted only minimal code. Please ask if need more. Is it not the right way, then what is it? Is there any good documentation or help available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you should have one `SnmpContext` object and multiple MIB trees each registered with `SnmpContext` under some distinct name.

```
# Create an SNMP context with default ContextEngineId (same as SNMP engine ID)
snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

# Create multiple independent trees of MIB managed objects (empty so far)
mibTreeA = instrum.MibInstrumController(builder.MibBuilder())
mibTreeB = instrum.MibInstrumController(builder.MibBuilder())

# Register MIB trees at distinct SNMP Context names
snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('context-a'), mibTreeA)
snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('context-b'), mibTreeB)

# Register SNMP Applications at the SNMP engine for particular SNMP context
cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.BulkCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
```

Then you should be able to query each of the MIB trees like this:

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u usr-md5-none -l authNoPriv -A authkey1 -n context-a 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6
snmpwalk -v3 -u usr-md5-none -l authNoPriv -A authkey1 -n context-b 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6
```

You will likely get just end-of-mib because MIB trees are empty.

Here is a hopefully operational [example script](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#multiple-mib-trees-under-distinct-context-names).

Alternatively to implementing your own SNMP agent from the scratch, you might consider trying out [SNMP Command Responder](http://snmplabs.com/snmpresponder/) tool based on the same technology, but making it easier (hopefully).

Comment: So if I want to add something to MIB trees should  I add like this mibTreeA = instrum.MibInstrumController(builder.MibBuilder().loadmodules()) ?

Comment: MYTEST-PANEL-DATA::cc1-Test-Status = No more variables left in this 
MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree) . Now this is  what I am getting. Could you please tell something regarding adding data to the MIB tree.I couldn't find any document or good samples.

Comment: You should call [loadModules()](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/builder.py#L411) on `MibBuilder` object to populate MIB tree. You also need to have your managed objects [implemented](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/tree/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances) in the MIB you load up. Also, some relevant documentation can be found [here](http://snmplabs.com/snmpresponder/).

Comment: Thank you Ilya Etingof, You said "You also need to have your managed objects implemented in the MIB you load up, "could you please explain what we need to do for it or give some examples for it.